# input data overwriting JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When I press the "save" button to store my API key, the JSON file replaces my existing Steam64ID by removing it from the file instead of not interfering with it. Any help will be appreicated.

```
//Save API Key to JSON
saveapi.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const apiKey = apibox.value;
  const data = { apikey: apiKey };
  const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  window.electronAPI.writeFile(jsonStr);
});

//Save Steam64 ID to JSON
savesteam64.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const steam64id = steam64box.value;
  const data = { steam64id: steam64id };
  const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  window.electronAPI.writeFile(jsonStr);
});
```

```
{
  "apikey": ""
  "steam64id": "" //This gets removed when I try save the api key
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing occurs because each time you save the API key or the Steam64ID, you're overwriting the entire JSON file with a new object that contains only one of these properties. To preserve the existing data in the JSON file, you need to first read the current contents of the file, update the relevant property, and then write the modified object back to the file.

Here's how you can modify your event listeners to achieve this:

```
// Function to read the current JSON data, update it, and write it back
function updateJsonData(updateKey, updateValue) {
  window.electronAPI.readFile((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error reading file:', err);
      return;
    }
    
    // Parse the existing JSON, or create a new object if the file is empty
    let jsonData = data ? JSON.parse(data) : {};
    
    // Update the specific key with the new value
    jsonData[updateKey] = updateValue;

    // Write the updated JSON back to the file
    const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2);
    window.electronAPI.writeFile(jsonStr);
  });
}

// Save API Key to JSON
saveapi.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const apiKey = apibox.value;
  updateJsonData('apikey', apiKey);
});

// Save Steam64 ID to JSON
savesteam64.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const steam64id = steam64box.value;
  updateJsonData('steam64id', steam64id);
});
```

In this code, updateJsonData is a new function that handles reading the existing JSON file, updating it with the new value for either apikey or steam64id, and then writing the updated JSON back to the file. This approach ensures that you keep the existing data intact while updating only the necessary part of the JSON.

Note: Make sure that your electronAPI.readFile and electronAPI.writeFile functions are set up to handle the reading and writing processes correctly, including error handling. The provided code assumes these functions are implemented to handle their respective tasks.